# Android development for beginners

Tags: android

I want to learn Android development and create mobile apps. What would be the recommended resources (There's too many on the web)?

Comment: Have you find a good book for learning?

Comment: take the best of any online resourse you fill comfortable with..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html & http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html, this should be enough for starters.

If you really learn and exercise what's written there you'll have a very solid foundation. Many other pages might be good but that's where you should start because you'll always come back and learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested, http://developer.android.com/index.html should be the bible for learning android. Moreover, as the world of Android is too wide, I would suggest you to take up an idea (NO matter if it is very simple) and then try to search out blogs and tutorials on the particular features you want to implement in the same idea.

Even [GitHub](https://github.com/) provides a lot of ready projects. clone them and try to understand the implementation by [Googling](https://www.google.co.in/) the unknown packages and words.

This would give you a better learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Defiantly check out the blogs, they helped me so much! I also emailed the authors and they really provided great feedback. Also, when you have an app, ask your family and friends for advice! This blog helped me so much! http://www.droidnova.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try Basic4Android, google it, i do not intend to spam. It will get you started with the OS and if you don't want to stay with basic go to java with knowledge.